# Insert, Inner Join and limit characters in one

Tags: mysql

I am trying to copy data from Table: oc_product_description Column: name to Table: Et Column: title but I need to copy only the left 125 characters as I have a limit of how many characters I can have.
I am thinking about something like this but it is not working

```
Insert into Et (title)
        INNER JOIN oc_product_description 
             ON oc_product_description.product_id = Et.product_id;
Select left(col, 125) col
From oc_product_description.name;
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I solved it with this:   Update Et
 INNER JOIN oc_product_description 
             ON oc_product_description.product_id = Et.product_id
Set Et.title=SUBSTRING(oc_product_description.name,1,125);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I fixed it

```
  Update Et
     INNER JOIN oc_product_description 
                 ON oc_product_description.product_id = Et.product_id
    Set Et.title=SUBSTRING(oc_product_description.name,1,125);
```

Comment: Try not to do what you did, ok. Some other user might have flagged you, and also try to be clear with what you ask for, nice to hear you found  solution and you share it.

Comment: @JonathanS., Sorry did not know the right way to do it. but I figured it out using your help. Also I think, the 0 should be 1 in your code also.

Answer (score 1):

You could also use `SUBSTRING` that is equivalent to `LEFT` like this:

(query cleaned)

```
INSERT INTO Et (title)
SELECT SUBSTRING(oc.name,0,125)
FROM oc_product_description AS oc 
INNER JOIN  Et AS e 
ON oc.product_id = e.product_id;
```

Comment: I get the following error when using this.  #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'SELECT SUBSTRING(oc.name,0,125) FROM oc_product_description AS oc INNER JOIN ' at line 2

Comment: Sorry @Schwann when using `INSERT ... SELECT` there's no need for VALUES clause